# Random number that is maybe part of intervall with a exponential distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, exponential

i got stuck with a problem, which is, that i need to generate a random number that could be part of an exponential distributed intervall, but i don't know how to do this in the programming language R.

I want to simulate radioactive decay. So if we have a given time window, which is an intervall (a,b] and the disintegration time x of an atom is part of (a,b] i want to increment a counter as the atom has decayed.

So, e.g. 100 atoms, how many have decayed afer a certain time window, if every atom has its own disintegration time.

My problem now: How do i get a random number, so that the number could be part of that time window but does not have to be?

My code so far:

```
#indicator function returns 1 if ti is part of the intervall otherwise 0
indicator<-function(timewindow,decaytime) {
  if(0 < decaytime || decaytime <= timewindow){
    return(1)
  }else{
    return(0)
  }
}

#ti should return the random number that could be part of the intervall HERE IS THE PROBLEM probably
getRandom<- function(p){
  number<- rexp(1, rate=p)
  return(number)
}

decay <- function(N,p,timewindow) {
    print(sum(replicate(N, indicator(timewindow,getRandom(p)))))
}

N<-100 #number of atoms
timewindow<-7.5 #time window (0 to 7.5]
p<-3.8/N #rate (lambda)

decay(N,p,t)
```

Comment: Between same-named functions/variables (`ti`, `t`), unused params (`t` in `ti(p,t)`), and the description, I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Is there a reason you cannot just use `decaytimes <- rexp(N, rate=p)` with `table(a < decaytimes & decaytimes <=  b)`?

Comment: sorry, i edited the code.
So the problem is, every atom's decay time is independant of each other. Therefore, every atom has its own decay time which is in addition exponential distributed. So my question, how can i get a number that is with a certain probability part of the timewindow so that the atom can be counted as decayed?

Comment: oh dear, i think i found my mistake. it's here: if(0 < decaytime || decaytime <= timewindow){ 
it should be && instead of || 
i should go get some sleep...
thanks for your support

Comment: I still don't see an issue. `rexp(N, rate=p)` gives 100 independent random numbers. For instance, `set.seed(2); rexp(3);` gives 1.86, 0.40, and 0.15 (rounded), which appears to be centered near the rate of 1. Once you have the vector of decay times, just do a vectorized comparison of `decaytimes < a & decaytimes <= b` (notice the single pipe for vectors), which will return a vector of `logical`, indicating which atoms decayed in that time period.